Is there a way to create a run configuration for a manage.py command in Pycharm
I want to be able to run a manage.py management command via a Pycharm run configuration.  Is there a way to do this?

What problem do you face? You can just run it like any other script.

You can configure this as a simple Python process where you invoke the manage.py script with the correct interpreter, and use management_command --settings=my_project.settings  as parameters:


Thanks, I'm relatively new to Python and Pycharm
